# Iframe/CSS: Forcing Iframe to fit screen

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm currently trying to have an iframe fit the size of my screen, and any other user using it at different resolutions, except no matter what I try I'll either end up with the iframe being too small or the height being too large causing a double scroll bar. (The iframe and the page itself having scroll bars).

My objective is having the iframe fit only 85% width of the page (which works!), 100px from the top of the screen (also works), and then for the bottom to fit the edge of the bottom of my browser (that's where I'm stuck...)

**HTML**

```
<div id="maindiv" class="maindiv">
<iframe id="theiframe" class="iframeautowidth" seamless src="http://whateverdomain.com></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.maindiv {
width: 85%; 
top: 100px;
}

.iframeautowidth {
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 85%;
height: 100%;
border: 0
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
margin: 0;
float: left;
}
```

If it counts for anything, I have the latest jquery running on my page if it'll help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the point in a giant iframe?

Comment: Tabbing system; so that the iframe will fill all of the page except the 100px I have to myself on top.

Comment: You should use ordinary links & no iframe (overflow'd area instead), with _redundant_ XHR for instant loading if you really want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onload()` event of your iframe and the `onresize()` event of the window to resize the iframe to the required size.

[This Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278469) explains it well.

FYI, in javascript `screen.width` & `screen.height` will give you the screen resolution.

Comment: `screen.width` and `screen.height` is useless here as screen size **!=** available size to your webpage.

Comment: Gave it my shot. Added the javascript and the two values to my DIV and Iframe (and switched them around to make sure I hadn't confused myself), also tried removing my CSS lines to get it working, no luck. With my CSS the iframe goes to 85% of the page, but has the height of maybe 150px, while without my CSS it's just simply a box. Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: p.s. Use innerHeight/clientHeight instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you had Fx4, a simple `height: -moz-calc(100%-100px)` would work a wonder. A pity this feature is introduced and supported so late in CSS3.

Comment: I do have fx4, unfortunately I need to make it as cross browser compatible as possible. >_< Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If the 100px top is for tabs navigating the iframe, there may be a workaround. Just fill up your iframe to 100% height and then put those tabs **inside** the iframes as another iframe with a fixed size. Or just resort to frameset.

Whether this works for you or not depends on your exact design, but hope that helps.